# When a disease 'comes back'

Tags: word-request

My uncle has DDD (Degenerative Disc Disease). He took treatments you know therapy, medication and stuff and has been all well for a year and now he's complaining about the same pain he had a year ago because he picked up a heavy load last week.

What English verb can be used to describe a disease *coming back* (usually after an improvement)? I'd be glad to put an example here to provide the context but I'm not sure how this verb is used in a sentence i.e. with a personal subject here *my uncle* or an impersonal one like *DDD* here.

Comment: [*relapse*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/relapse)

Comment: @user3169 Perfect :) thank you. I checked the example in LDOCE and I tried to use it in my own context. Is _"my uncle relapsed into DDD"_ natural to a native ear?

Comment: You can also say "my uncle suffered a relapse".

Comment: "He suffers a relapse" is good, or it [recurs](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recur), it [flares up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/flare+up) again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Relapse", as several have already mentioned in comments, is the natural word to use. It's specifically medical, and while it's a reasonably technical term, it's also familiar to most laymen, so you don't need to worry about it sounding unusual.

In the case of some ailments like cancer or cysts, "relapse" is not usually used; rather, the cancer "recurs" after a "remission" in which the cancerous growths are reduced in size and effect. I suspect it's because relapse carries a bit more of the connotation of a *systemic* or broader effect returning, while a recurrence has to do with the *existence* of something specific. But this is not a hard and fast rule; fevers can recur as well.